# exponential sum on complex numbers with a prime number

Tags: analysis

how you describe this sum? i don't have any idea. i tried to solve it by trigonometric way but I couldn't.

$$\sum_{h = 1}^p {{e^{\frac{{2\pi ih}}{p}}}}  = -1$$

$p$ is a prime number

Comment: [Geometrical series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series): $\sum_{h=1}^p x^h$ with $x = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$

Comment: Except the equation the OP wrote is incorrect; it comes out to 0.

Comment: Oh, they probably meant the sum only from $h=1$ to $p-1$, not all the way to $p$.

Comment: @AlexMeiburg you know the answer?

Comment: DonAntonio's answer explains the computation. But $0 = \sum_{h=1}^p f(h) = f(p) + \sum_{h=1}^{p-1} \implies \sum_{h=1}^{p-1} = -f(p) = -e^{2\pi i} = -1$.

Comment: @AlexMeiburg thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{h=1}^p\left(e^{2\pi i/p}\right)^h=e^{2\pi i/p}\frac{1-e^{2\pi ip/p}}{1-e^{2\pi i/p}}=0$$

so either you've a mistake or else the upper limit is different.